# git branch is behind origin/branch by 1 commit

Tags: git, git-commit

My branch is behind origin/branch because I accidentally pushed (there were no changes from the last commit) without adding or committing and then ran `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.

EDITED:
One strange thing is, the changes I made in my last commit are showing up in my remote branch, but also appear as staged changes (I can make it staged or unstaged in VScode, but the fact that they locally appear as not committed yet).
The command prompt says that I can `git pull` to fast forward but it didn't do anything.
How can I fix this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: what's `git diff origin/branch`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity the command didn't output anything

Comment: OK, and if you do `git log`, what's the last commit you see? What happens if you compare that with what's on the remote, are you missing a commit locally?

Comment: Yeah, remote has 1 more commit that I don't see in `git log`. The commit that only exists in the remote has the last changes I made that locally appear as not-committed

Comment: OK. How about `git fetch origin branch` and then `git reset --hard origin/branch`?

Comment: First of all, if I look at the description of what you have done and the result you get, I don't see anything wrong: this is exactly what is expected. Now, I don't understand what you want to do next. Do you want to align your local branch to the one on the remote to continue working ? Or do you want to completely discard your latest commit from the remote and the local branch ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I want to make my local branch (and so `git log`) to look like my remote branch without missing the commit

Comment: @ignoring_gravity your method helped my local to look like the remote. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you run `git pull` you will simply return to the situation before your `git reset --soft`.

---

The fact that the differences are staged is the expected effect of the `--soft` in `git reset`.